# Django 2 implement Other user's Profile View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.1) in which I need to implement a view for users to view other user's profile, I have implemented the view, it shows the profile but displaying the profile information.

Here what I have tried:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='/assets/images/avatar.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
class UserProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        user_profile = ProfileModel.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=username))
        gigs = Gig.objects.filter(user__username=username, status=True)
        print(user_profile.values())
        return render(request, 'jobexpertapp/profile.html', {'user_profile': user_profile, 'gigs': gigs,
                                                             'name': username})
```

**From `templates/profile.html`:**

```
{% if name == user.username %}
    #, In this case, I will add a, `edit` button and display other 
     info
    # the info in this case id displaying correctly
{% else %}
    # Here I need to display other user's info e.g
    <h1> {{ user_profile.slogan }}</h1>
```

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your question - what is the problem?

Comment: What does "it shows the profile but displaying the profile information" mean?

Comment: Hi @RobinZigmond, There are some public posts created by the different user on the home page when user click on the author of any post it will go to that particular user profile, mean I want to show other users public profile.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, I mean there's no error on the template side, even when i ty to display something like: `{{ user_profile.first }}` then it display the other user's name but I want to get all public info of other user like his name, profile_pic, slogan and about.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, `{{ user_profile.first }}` will refers to the entire `Profile` object, which you have told Django to stringify as just the username - to access specific fields such as the slogan you just do `{{ user_profile.first.slogan }}`. Not sure if I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `filter` instead of `get` in your query, so it returns a queryset. That's why `first` works, since it then gets the first result for the queryset.

Use `get`:

```
user_profile = ProfileModel.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=username))
```

Note, this is more simply spelled:

```
user_profile = ProfileModel.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, how can I display the current user's profile info? I'm trying to access like that `{{user.profile.profile_pic}}`, but not getting that.

Comment: That's probably a separate question. But note that your models mean that you have potentially *multiple* profiles for each user; your `profile` related_name actually refers to a queryset, so you would need to do `user.profile.first.profile_pic` etc. (Really, you shouldn't set the `related_name` like that.) Probably you wanted a OneToOneField there anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot @Daniel Roseman! I have changed the `ForeginKey` to `OneToOneField` and then try to acces it directly!